# CPU comparisions

Tags: cpu, performance

I have an older computer which CPU-z says is an Intel i5 4570, 4 cores, clock speed 2.5ghz. I want to buy a new computer and the one I'm looking at as an Intel i7-11700, 8 cores, base clock speed 2.5 GHz with "turbo" up to 4.9 GHz. I know that CPU speed isn't everything. The new computer has an M.2 SSD vs HDD, more & faster memory than my old computer, etc.

My current computer is at least 5+ years old, but the newer processor has the same clock speed as this old one.  Despite all the Marketing mumbo-jumbo, the old computer and the new have the same base clock cycle.
The new one has more cores, but *I think that only helps if the applications in use are coded for using multiple cores.*

1. Does higher core count affect applications performance that are coded to use multiple cores?

The "turbo" part I kind of understand - the chip can run faster for short bursts but not full-time

2. Will it fry itself if it ran on max-clock at all time?
3. Why would I buy a new computer with the same processor base clock as my 5 year old computer?
4. Wouldn't I be better off getting a CPU with a faster base-clock like Intel Xeon W-1350P of 4 GHz and turbo up to 5.10 GHz to help future-proof it for as long as possible?

I don't know how to parse all the Marketing hype on new computers. Transistor size, core count, processor speed, turbo speed, etc. *I'm starting to get the feeling that none of this crap matters except processor speed* and that the rest of the numbers (transistor size, cores, cache, turbo, etc) isn't directly relevant. It all contributes to the performance.

5. Is faster CPU speed (base/turbo clocks) the best-choice for a new processor?

Can you help me cut through all the b.s. here and help me **figure out how to interpret new computer specs**, please?

Comment: Comparing a new generation CPU and fast SSD to an older generation CPU with a hard drive is comparing apples and oranges.

Comment: frequency hasn't changed in many years. see here: https://www.technologyreview.com/2010/10/12/199966/why-cpus-arent-getting-any-faster/  That said, newer generation chips do substantially out-perform those from a few generations back. its just harder to tell how, because the metrics we use to evaluate them are not expressing the major improvements, so my take is that you have it backward.

Comment: There's no such thing as "*future-proofing*" when it comes to personal computers.  It's not just processor speed/performance that changes/improves with time.  System interfaces (what happened to ISA, EISA, MicroChannel, PCI?) and memory technology (what happened to RAMBus, EDO, DDR?) on the motherboard evolve.  How you use a computer (e.g. what software tasks) and what you need to install or connect to is as salient as its performance.

Comment: CPUs have made generational improvements of anywhere between 5 and 15%, meaning that for the same task at the same clock speed a new processor should still give *some* improvements over the previous generation. With improving memory and storage speeds it is difficult to compare old and new systems in an easy way. Future proofing is a difficult thing as well. You could spend 3 to 4 times as much to get a Xeon (they are not priced for "normal" desktops) or you can save your money and upgrade sooner which gets you improvements in all the other components.

Comment: "*Can you help me cut through all the b.s. here and help me figure out how to interpret new computer specs, please?*" -- The practical way to evaluate system performance is to put aside technical specifications, and perform a benchmark of the applications that you will actually use.  But be wary of specific benchmark programs (i.e. programs that have no utility other than generate a performance number), as some CPUs/systems have been known to be specifically tweaked to  generate good numbers.

Comment: This question doesn’t seem like a great fit for Super User. It seems fairly vague or unclear what you are looking for. Would you be able to edit your question to be more specific?

Answer (score 3):

TL;DR: You can use [userbenchmark](https://cpu.userbenchmark.com/) to compare processors performance.

---

As I understand you are looking for an upgrade option for your desktop computer. 
A PC building community forums (e.g., [Linus tech tips forum](https://linustechtips.com/)) may help you with the process of understanding specs and upgrade options. Also, they have multiple guides on their YouTube channel. [This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8QOoQWvrQ-Y) video is answering multiple of your questions about CPU specs.

---

Comparing CPUs using only specs might be deceiving, for example, architectural improvements can boost CPU performance while having nearly same specs (e.g., core count, base clock, etc).

**Example:** [i5-3470](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/products/sku/68316/intel-core-i53470-processor-6m-cache-up-to-3-60-ghz/specifications.html) and [i5-4460](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/products/sku/80817/intel-core-i54460-processor-6m-cache-up-to-3-40-ghz/specifications.html) have the same:

- core count
- thread count
- L2 cache size
- L3 cache size
- transistor size
- base clock speed

While [i5-3470](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/products/sku/68316/intel-core-i53470-processor-6m-cache-up-to-3-60-ghz/specifications.html) has higher CPU and integrated GPU turbo clock speeds, [i5-4460](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/products/sku/80817/intel-core-i54460-processor-6m-cache-up-to-3-40-ghz/specifications.html) is slightly better according to my experience of using them and some users reports (e.g, [SkuezTech](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=US_n_vvaIbw) and [Albania Gaming](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n97iGDChbsI)). Whether to trust those reports is another question I can't answer.

The 4th Gen i5 could reach higher performance with lower turbo clock speed is because an architecture upgrade, `Haswell` vs the older `Ivy Bridge`. More information about [difference between Intel's Haswell and Ivy Bridge CPUs](https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/so-whats-the-difference-between-intels-haswell-and-ivy-bridge-cpus/).

That's why benchmarks are usually used for comparing CPUs performance. Whether these benchmarks translate to a better experience depends on your use case.

> The "turbo" part I kind of understand - the chip can run faster for short bursts but not full-time; it would fry itself if it ran full-time?

While idling, CPU [can run at a clock speed lower than the base clock speed](https://www.quora.com/Is-it-normal-for-a-CPUs-GHz-speed-to-be-lower-than-the-base-speed?share=1) to reduce power consumption without affecting performance. Also, a CPU can [maintain the maximum turbo speed](https://www.cgdirector.com/cpu-base-clocks-vs-boost-clocks/) while running a continuous heavy loud if provided enough cooling without getting fried. Additionally, modern CPUs will [thermal throttle](https://www.technipages.com/what-is-thermal-throttling) if it got too hot.